# How to say "I have been running for 3 years."

Tags: tiempos-verbales, pretérito

I have always learned that it is best to use the construction:

> Hace tres años que corro.

or

> Corro desde hace tres años.

or **EDIT** (*lentic catachresis*)

> Llevo tres años corriendo.
>   Vengo corriendo desde hace tres años.

Is there a subtle difference in meaning with this:
(since it is a direct translation in the preterite perfect progressive) ?

> He estado corriendo desde hace 3 años.

**EDIT:** Changed from *desde* to *desde hace* here.

Does it mean the exact same thing, but just not used as much? It seems to me they both describe a past event that continues in the present.  Does *desde hace* work here?

Thanks,
Jonathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two forms that you have work well with your edits.

The different ways you can talk about how long something has been going on are:

- Llevo [período] haciendo algo…
- Llevo [período] en hacer algo…
- He estado haciendo algo por [período] <sub>(and I'll keep doing it)</sub>
- He estado haciendo algo desde hace [período] <sub>(and I'll keep doing it)</sub>
- Hago algo desde hace [período]
- Es/son [período] ya que hago algo <sub>(strong emphasis on length)</sub>
- Estoy en hacer algo por [período] <sub>(but I'm not done yet)</sub>
- [período] ha que hago algo <sub>(very formal)</sub>
- Vengo haciendo algo desde hace [período] <sub>(rioplatense)</sub>

That list is of course nonexhaustive.  There are probably many other ways that don't immediately come to my mind and all have some slight difference in meaning/usage, though effectively synonymous.

Your thoughts on using *tiene* (in one of your comments) probably comes from the *ha* usage.  Portuguese uses this one as the normal construction (*Tres anos há que faço algo*) but curiously Brazilian Portuguese, which generally avoids *haver*, substitutes with *ter* (*Tem três anos que faço algo*).  Perhaps you heard a Portuñol expression that was *Tiene tres años que hago algo* or similar, but it'd definitely not be considered Standard Spanish.

Comment: @Jonathan, you might mark this answer (or any other) as accepted.

Comment: "Faz três anos que faço algo" is also usual in Brazilian Portuguese.

Answer (score 2):

Antes que nada, dos alternativas:

> Llevo tres años corriendo.

o

> Vengo corriendo desde hace tres años.

La segunda puede acusar un cierto regionalismo rioplatense, no me doy bien cuenta.

"He estado corriendo desde tres años" no está bien. A lo sumo podría ser "He estado corriendo desde hace tres años": esta es una frase gramaticalmente correcta pero que se me antoja artificial.

Comment: Could you also use "tiene + time"? I thought I have seen that somewhere.  "Corro tiene tres años."

Comment: @Jonathan: no, that's not a correct sentence.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best one is

> Llevo tres años corriendo.

It's the more natural way to say it! However

> He estado corriendo desde hace tres años

Is fine too, but it gives an idea of "I will keep on running".

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends heavily on the context.  The first two options mentioned seem to me to be correct in a reasonable sense.  The rest of the choices seem to me a bit comical without a context (as if you were saying it WHILE you were running).

Answer (score 0):

> llevo tres años corriendo

Makes sense and more natural than the other ones.

> He estado corriendo desde tres años

Does not make sense but you could say

> He estado corriendo durante tres años